# Closed form (or simplification) of recurrence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Could anyone help to derive a closed form of the following recurrence sequence? (or any comments?)

$N, M$ are positive integers and $\sigma$ is a positive real number.

\begin{align}
c_0 &= \frac{1}{M^N}, \\
c_m &= \frac{M^N}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^k (kN-m+k)}{k!(M+k) \sigma^{2k}} c_{m-k}.
\end{align}

Comment: Have you tried generating functions?